# Python Requests: Post JSON and file in single request

Tags: python, json, urllib2

I need to do a API call to upload a file along with a JSON string with details about the file.

I am trying to use the python requests lib to do this:

```
import requests

info = {
    'var1' : 'this',
    'var2'  : 'that',
}

data = json.dumps({
    'token' : auth_token,
    'info'  : info,
})

headers = {'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}

files = {'document': open('file_name.pdf', 'rb')}

r = requests.post(url, files=files, data=data, headers=headers)
```

This throws the following error:

```
    raise ValueError("Data must not be a string.")
 ValueError: Data must not be a string
```

If I remove the 'files' from the request, it works.
If I remove the 'data' from the request, it works.
If I do not encode data as JSON it works.

For this reason I think the error is to do with sending JSON data and files in the same request.

Any ideas on how to get this working?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Don't encode using json.

```
import requests

info = {
    'var1' : 'this',
    'var2'  : 'that',
}

data = {
    'token' : auth_token,
    'info'  : info,
}

headers = {'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}

files = {'document': open('file_name.pdf', 'rb')}

r = requests.post(url, files=files, data=data, headers=headers)
```

Note that this may not necessarily be what you want, as it will become another form-data section.

Comment: If I do as you suggest, I get another exception: "need more than 1 value to unpack" and wonder what to do with it :-(

Comment: This will only work if `data` are simple key-value pairs (form parameters-like), but all nested stuff will be truncated as HTTP form-encoding is not capable of representing nested data structures.

Comment: Thanks, @hoefling. You've saved my life. I was trying to understand for 1 hour why the hell that library truncates it (or what was happening).

Comment: @proteneer This does not seems to be working for me, 
Doing a call like . 
`d = requests.post('http://localhost:18090/upload',files={ 'face_image': ('mama_justkilled_aman.jpg', open('mama_justkilled_aman.jpg', 'rb'), 'image/jpeg' ) }, data={ 'gffp': 42 })`  

but data is not being received by the server

Comment: @hoefling, thanks for your remark. the comment here was working for nested stuff in my case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35946962/2254425

Comment: @BalaKrishna isn't working for me too, server doesn't see data :(

Answer (score 40):

See this thread [How to send JSON as part of multipart POST-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35939761/how-to-send-json-as-part-of-multipart-post-request#comment59538358_35939761)

***Do not set the Content-type header yourself, leave that to pyrequests to generate***

```
def send_request():
    payload = {"param_1": "value_1", "param_2": "value_2"}
    files = {
        'json': (None, json.dumps(payload), 'application/json'),
        'file': (os.path.basename(file), open(file, 'rb'), 'application/octet-stream')
    }

    r = requests.post(url, files=files)
    print(r.content)
```

Comment: let's say Flask is the receiver what would be the way to code flask for that ?

Comment: @Mouldri try `response.data`

Comment: @MouIdri  it would be ```request.form['json']```

Comment: @DanSalo  thanks, i forgot to answer, I did find it a will. thanks for your confirmation ( upvoted your comments )

Comment: you're the real mvp ! this tricks works for nested data object, that's great ! thanks

Comment: this one worked for me, but  how do we send multiple file in this ?

Answer (score 3):

I'm don't think you can send both data and files in a multipart encoded file, so you need to  make your data a "file" too:

```
files = {
    'data' : data,
    'document': open('file_name.pdf', 'rb')
}

r = requests.post(url, files=files, headers=headers)
```

Comment: How would you decode that? Client would get a python dict not JSON right? it's a question!

Comment: @sabik: requests encodes the dictionary as form data.

Comment: To note: on the receiving end: the ```request.files['data']``` is a fileStorage tuple.  What needs to be done is do a ```request.files['data'].read()``` to get the actual data (which is a json-encoded string) so you'll need to  do something like ```json.loads(request.files['data'].read())```

Answer (score 2):

I have been using `requests==2.22.0`

For me , the below code worked.

```
import requests


data = {
    'var1': 'this',
    'var2': 'that'
}

r = requests.post("http://api.example.com/v1/api/some/",
    files={'document': open('doocument.pdf', 'rb')},
    data=data,
    headers={"Authorization": "Token jfhgfgsdadhfghfgvgjhN"}. #since I had to authenticate for the same
)

print (r.json())
```

Answer (score 1):

For sending Facebook Messenger API, I changed all the payload dictionary values to be strings.  Then, I can pass the payload as `data` parameter.

```
import requests

ACCESS_TOKEN = ''

url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages'
payload = {
        'access_token' : ACCESS_TOKEN,
        'messaging_type' : "UPDATE",
        'recipient' : '{"id":"1111111111111"}',
        'message' : '{"attachment":{"type":"image", "payload":{"is_reusable":true}}}',
}
files = {'filedata': (file, open(file, 'rb'), 'image/png')}
r = requests.post(url, files=files, data=payload)
```

Answer (score 1):

**1. Sending request**

```
import json
import requests

cover   = 'superneat.jpg'
payload = {'title': 'The 100 (2014)', 'episodes': json.dumps(_episodes)}
files   = [
            ('json', ('payload.json', json.dumps(payload), 'application/json')),
            ('cover', (cover, open(cover, 'rb')))
          ]
r       = requests.post("https://superneatech.com/store/series", files=files)

print(r.text)
```

**2. Receiving request**

*You will receive the JSON data as a file, get the content and continue...*

**Reference:** [View Here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#post-multiple-multipart-encoded-files)

Answer (score -1):

What is more:

```
files = {
    'document': open('file_name.pdf', 'rb')
}
```

That will only work if your file is at the same directory where your script is.

If you want to append file from different directory you should do:

```
files = {
    'document': open(os.path.join(dir_path, 'file_name.pdf'), 'rb')
}
```

Where **dir_path** is a directory with your **'file_name.pdf'** file.

But what if you'd like to send multiple PDFs ?

You can simply make a custom function to return a list of files you need (in your case that can be only those with **.pdf** extension). That also includes files in subdirectories (search for files recursively):

```
def prepare_pdfs():
    return sorted([os.path.join(root, filename) for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(dir_path) for filename in filenames if filename.endswith('.pdf')])
```

Then you can call it:

```
my_data = prepare_pdfs()
```

And with simple loop:

```
for file in my_data:

    pdf = open(file, 'rb')

    files = {
        'document': pdf
    }

    r = requests.post(url, files=files, ...)
```

Comment: The last code block is terrible. That's a DDoS attack! Don't do that.