# Python Request: Post Images on Facebook using Multipart/form-data

Tags: python, facebook, python-requests, multipartform-data

I'm using the facebook API to post images on a page, I can post image from web using this :

```
import requests

data = 'url=' + url + '&caption=' + caption + '&access_token=' + token
status = requests.post('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/PAGE_ID/photos',
                       data=data)
print status
```

But when I want to post a local image (using multipart/form-data) i get the error : `ValueError: Data must not be a string.`

I was using this code:

```
data = 'caption=' + caption + '&access_token=' + token
files = {
    'file': open(IMG_PATH, 'rb')
    }

status = requests.post('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/PAGE_ID/photos',
                       data=data, files=files)
print status
```

I read ([Python Requests: Post JSON and file in single request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19439961/python-requests-post-json-and-file-in-single-request/19440099#19440099)) that maybe it's not possible to send both data and files in a multipart encoded file so I updated my code :

```
data = 'caption=' + caption + '&access_token=' + token
files = {
    'data': data,
    'file': open(IMG_PATH, 'rb')
    }

status = requests.post('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/PAGE_ID/photos',
                       files=files)
print status
```

But that doesn't seem to work, I get the same error as above.
Do you guys know why it's not working, and maybe a way to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass in `data` as a *dictionary*:

```
data = {
    'caption', caption,
    'access_token', token
}
files = {
    'file': open(IMG_PATH, 'rb')
}
status = requests.post(
    'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/PAGE_ID/photos',
     data=data, files=files)
```

`requests` can't produce `multipart/form-data` parts (together with the files you are uploading) from a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoded string.

Using a dictionary for the POST data has the additional advantage that `requests` takes care of properly encoding the values; `caption` especially could contain data that you must escape properly.

Comment: Which 'name' does the content-disposition header use for sending along such a dictionary of json data? I can't find this anywhere, but would really like to make use of it in my C# program. Currently I'm stuck adding multiple bits of StringContent to my MultipartFormDataContent.

Comment: Hi, How to upload multiple photo using same method. I tried putting two item in files dict . It stills upload one photo.

Comment: @ascii_walker: the page photos API doesn't support uploading multiple photos in a single request. See the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/photos/#Creating): *You can upload and publish a single photo in one API request.*

Comment: In using this, can files dict contain multiple images that could then be all posted together in one post on facebook?

Comment: No, it can’t. See my previous comment.

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters. It saved mine R&D time.