# Posting comments with images to Facebook with requests

Tags: python, facebook, python-requests

I'm very very new to the Facebook API and I've been trying post comments with images and have had no luck.
I found a script that posts comments with the `requests` module but I am having trouble with getting it to post an image attachment.

I first tried it like this:

```
def comment_on_posts(posts, amount):
    counter = 0 
    for post in posts: 
        if counter >= amount: 
            break 
        else: 
            counter = counter + 1 
        url = "https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/comments".format(post['id']) 
        message = "message here"
        dir = os.listdir("./assets/imagedir")
        imageFile = f"./assets/imagedir/{dir[0]}"
        img = {open(imageFile, 'rb')}
        parameters = {'access_token' : access_token, 'message' : message, 'file' : img}
        s = requests.post(url, data = parameters)
        print("Submitted comment successfully!")
        print(s)
```

`print(s)` returns `<Response [200]>`

The comment posts... but the image does not appear on the comment.

I read on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38633791/python-request-post-images-on-facebook-using-multipart-form-data) that requests does not produce multipart/form

So I tried this:

```
url = "https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/comments".format(post['id']) 
        message = "message here"
        dir = os.listdir("./assets/imagedir")
        imageFile = f"./assets/imagedir/{dir[0]}"
        img = {open(imageFile, 'rb')}
        data = {'access_token' : access_token, 'message' : message}
        files = {'file' : img}
        s = requests.post(url, data = data, files = files)
        print("Posted comment successfully")
        print(s)
```

Now I'm getting the error : `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'set'`

I'm really not sure what to do here. Maybe there is a better way of accomplishing this?
Any help is appreciated.

I've slightly modified the script from [this post](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-write-a-Python-script-to-comment-automatically-on-each-post-of-a-Facebook-page). All credit for this code goes to them.

I've only modified `comment_on_posts` and some optional values from the original script, everything else is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the `source` field (not `file` ) field as in [Facebook Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/object/comments/#publish) and pass the image as `multipart/form-data`:

```
import requests

post_id = '***'
access_token = '***'
message = '***'
image_path = '***'

url = f'https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/{post_id}/comments'
data = {'message': message, 'access_token': access_token}
files = {'source': open(image_path, 'rb')}

requests.post(url, params=data, files=files)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this worked. However, I am running into an issue. I'm getting `<Response [403]>`. I gave it the permissions `user_events`, `pages_show_list`, `pages_read_engagement`, `pages_read_user_content`, `pages_manage_posts`, `pages_manage_engagement` and  `public_profile`. From what I've read in the documentation that should be all I need.

Comment: It worked for me many thanks! I was trying to use the graph api (with methods such as `graph.put_comment` and `graph.put_object`) but it didn't work