# Flask API to post data and image

Tags: api, flask, post

I am little confused. I want to create API that can post image, and  one dictionary along with that image. How can I do it ? for one image, I can do it like this. What if I want to post another variable which is not a file, lets say variable **meta_data**?

```
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/im_size'
my_img = {'image': open('test.jpg', 'rb')}
r = requests.post(url, files=my_img)
```

What change should be in my API script as well which is as follow

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/im_size", methods=["POST"])
def process_image():
    file = request.files['image']
    # Read the image via file.stream
    img = Image.open(file.stream)

    return jsonify({'msg': 'success', 'size': [img.width, img.height]})


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`requests.post` [supports a json argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26344315/2052575) which sets the correct content type (`'application/json'`) for that data to then be accessed via `request.get_json()` method in Flask.

However this plays up when you're also providing the `files` argument, which sets the content type to `'multipart/form-data'`.

With help from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47679227/using-python-to-send-json-and-files-to-flask) I found the solution is to send your JSON data as part of the multipart form.

So on the client define a dictionary, and add it to the `my_img` dict as follows:

```
import json

meta_data = {'message':'I am a picture', 'another_message':'About to upload'}

my_img = {'image': open('test.jpg', 'rb'),
          'json_data':  ('j', json.dumps(meta_data), 'application/json')}
```

Then on the server end you'll also need to `import json` and within your `process_image` view function you can access that data with:

```
    image = request.files['image'] # The Werkzeug FileStorage object.

    json_data = request.files['json_data']
    meta_data = json.load(json_data)

    print (meta_data)
    print (json_data.filename)
```

Server output:

```
{'message': 'I am a picture', 'another_message': 'About to upload'}
j
```