# How do I send BOTH a file and form data using requests in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, ibm-cloud, ibm-blockchain

I'm making the following call using the python requests library:

```
response = requests.post(
    'https://blockchain-starter.eu-gb.bluemix.net/api/v1/networks/<network id>/chaincode/install',
    headers={
        'accept':        'application/json',
        'content-type':  'multipart/form-data',
        'authorization': 'Basic  ' + b64encode(credential['key'] + ":" + credential['secret'])
    },
    data={
        'chaincode_id':      chaincode_id,
        'chaincode_version': new_version,
        'chaincode_type':    chaincode_type,
        'files':             open('chaincode.zip', 'rb')
    }
)
```

However when I make a call I get a 500 Internal Server Error (API is [this](https://blockchain-starter.eu-gb.bluemix.net/api-docs/), in particular [Peers / Install Chaincode](https://blockchain-starter.eu-gb.bluemix.net/api-docs/#/Peers/installChaincode)). Given that a call I have earlier to one of the GET endpoints is working correctly I assume there is something wrong with my request, can anyone help?

UPDATE:

Solution was to remove the `content-type` header and move the file upload into it's own `files` argument:

```
response = requests.post(
    https://blockchain-starter.eu-gb.bluemix.net/api/v1/networks/<network id>/chaincode/install,
    headers={
        'accept':        'application/json',
        'authorization': 'Basic  ' + b64encode(credential['key'] + ":" + credential['secret'])
    },
    data={
        'chaincode_id':      chaincode_id,
        'chaincode_version': new_version,
        'chaincode_type':    chaincode_language
    },
    files={
        'file': open('chaincode_id.zip', 'rb')
    }
)
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19439961/python-requests-post-json-and-file-in-single-request) help ?

Comment: Yes! Not the top answer but the second one.

To anyone interested, the solution is removing the `content-type` header and moving the files into it's own section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As acknowledged by the person asking the question, this answer by [ralf htp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5230735/ralf-htp) seems to have solved their issue.

> Do not set the Content-type header yourself, leave that to pyrequests to generate

```
def send_request():
payload = {"param_1": "value_1", "param_2": "value_2"}
files = {
     'json': (None, json.dumps(payload), 'application/json'),
     'file': (os.path.basename(file), open(file, 'rb'), 'application/octet-stream')
}

r = requests.post(url, files=files)
print(r.content)
```