# Post files with json data using python requests

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I have API that accepts multiple files with json data -

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:25965/v1/import \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-ba66a9b8d6cb' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -F 'files=@C:\Users\user\File1.xlsx' \
  -F 'files=@C:\Users\user\File2.xlsx' \
  -F 'files=@C:\Users\user\File3.xlsx' \
  -F 'values=[
   {
        "field1": "Value11",
        "field2": "Value21",
        "field3": "File1.xlsx"
    },
   {
        "field1": "Value21",
        "field2": "Value22",
        "field3": "File2.xlsx"
    },
   {
        "field1": "Value31",
        "field2": "Value32",
        "field3": "File3.xlsx"
    }
]'
```

I'm trying to convert this request into python.
With requests, I get error **too many values to unpack (expected 2)**

```
def PostFiles(self, apiName, values, files):
        url = self.ApiUrl + apiName 
        params = {}
        for file in files:
            params.update({'files':file})
        response = requests.post(url, 
                                 files=params,
                                 data=values,
                                 headers={
                                     'Content-Type':'application/json'},
                                 auth=HTTPKerberosAuth(delegate=True))
        return response
```

I also tried requests_toolbelt but doesn't work.

```
def PostFiles(self, apiName, values, files):
        url = self.ApiUrl + apiName  
        params = {}
        for file in files:
            params.update({'files':file})
        params.update({'values':json.dumps(values)})

        multipart_data = MultipartEncoder(params)

        headers = { 'Content-Type':multipart_data.content_type}
        response = requests.post(url, 
                                 data=multipart_data,
                                 headers=headers,
                                 auth=HTTPKerberosAuth(delegate=True))
        return response
```

---

this is my function call -

```
 files = [open(join(directory, filename), 'rb')]
    #files = [('files',(filename, open(join(directory, filename), 'rb'),'application/vnd.ms-excel'))]
    values = [{
             'field1': 'value11',
             'field2' : 'value21',
             'field3' : 'File1.xlsx'
        }]
    response = PostFiles('import', values, files)
    print(response)
```

there are posts related to this topic but I couldn't find anything with multiple files posting with json.

Answer (score 0):

I modified my code as per [Post JSON and file in single request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19439961/python-requests-post-json-and-file-in-single-request) and worked as expected.

```
def PostFiles(self, apiName, values, files):
        url = self.ApiUrl + apiName 
        params = {
            'values': (None, json.dumps(values), 'application/json')
            }
        for file in files:
            params.update({'files':file})
        response = requests.post(url, 
                                 files=params,
                                 auth=HTTPKerberosAuth(delegate=True))
        result = response.json()
        if response.status_code != 200 :
            raise Exception(result)
        return json.dumps(result)
```