# Pass files with json payload in single requests to web2py endpoint

Tags: python, python-requests, python-unittest, web2py, pythonanywhere

I wrote endpoint called `foobar` in `default.py` controller of **web2py**, it looks like

```
@service.json
def foobar(*args, **vars):
    payload = request.vars.student
    print(payload)
    #Above payload prints [rollNo, firstName, lastName]
    #Expected is {"rollNo": 6299857, "FirstName": Prasad, "LastName": Telkikar}

    fileObj= request.vars.video
    studentActivity = fileObj.file.read()
    
    #Currently I am unable to do it from unit test, but it works from postman
    print(f"Student's Roll number = {payload.rollNo} \n FirstName = {payload.firstName},  \n lastName = {payload.lastName}, fileSize = {fileObj.file.tell()}")

    #storing studentActivity video to specific location
    #Doing business logic
```

Now I am writing unit test for this endpoint, where i am trying to call this endpoint using `requests`,

```
import requests
import unittest

...
    
class TestStudentsData(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_Individual_student(self):
        payload = dict(rollNo=6299857, firstName="Prasad", lastName="Telkikar")
        url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/foobar"
        header = dict(Authorization="Bearer <Token>")
        response = requests.post(url,files={'studentActivity':open("Activity.mp4", 'rb')},  data=payload, headers=headers)

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

Here I am unable to pass student payload as a `json`.

> How can I pass `json` payload with `studentActivity` file using requests?

---

What I tried so far?

- I tried both the approaches given in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19439961).
- I read `requests` documentation where it says *"the json parameter is ignored if either data or files is passed"* [requests documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem by adding proper `content-type` to `payload`,

```
import os

...

filePath = os.getcwd()
files = {'studentActivity':open(filePath, "Activity.mp4", 'rb'), 
             'payload':(None, payload, 'application/json')}
                                       #^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ This was missing
 
response = requests.post(url,files={'studentActivity':open("Activity.mp4", 'rb')},  data=payload, headers=headers)
```