# How to send spacy doc object as payload in a REST api request and reconstruct the spacy doc object back inside the api?

Tags: python, spacy

I have spacy object of type <class 'spacy.tokens.doc.Doc'>

```
import spacy
import requests
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
spacy_doc = nlp("hello")
```

How can I send this object as payload in a api request? Currently when I try to post it using below code

```
requests.post(API_URL, json={'doc': spacy_doc}, timeout=3)
```

I am getting the below error

```
ERROR:Object of type 'Doc' is not JSON serializable
```

Doc.to_bytes() is mentioned in https://spacy.io/usage/saving-loading

but when I use it

```
requests.post(API_URL, json={'doc': spacy_doc.to_bytes()}, timeout=3)
```

I get

```
ERROR:Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable
```

What is the correct way to send spacy doc and reconstruct it back in the api(I am developing this target api service and its made using fastapi)?

Comment: Can you add the code snippet that caused the error?

Comment: Just added the code. Shaji pappan enthu parayunnu?

Answer (score 1):

using [**`.to_json()`**--(doc)](https://spacy.io/api/doc#to_json) will convert the doc to a JSON and which can be sent over the network.

```
requests.post(API_URL, json={'doc': spacy_doc.to_json()}, timeout=3)
```

Comment: How do we reconstruct it back to spacy doc object once we recieve it in the api? I dont see corresponding from_json() spacy method.

Comment: I am not quite good at spaCy, but, you might need to use form-data to send raw bytes, afaik, JSON not compatible with bytes.

Comment: Good idea. Is it possible to send bytes as form data and also send regular json in a singe post request.

Comment: I don't think you can send form-data and json at the same time. But, [I found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19439961/python-requests-post-json-and-file-in-single-request), might be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to serialize the doc objects:

Often it’s sufficient to use the Doc.to_array functionality to serialize docs and just serialize the numpy arrays – but other times you want a more general way to save and restore Doc objects.

The [DocBin](https://spacy.io/api/docbin) class makes it easy to [serialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633402/what-is-serialization) and deserialize a collection of Doc objects together, and is much more efficient than calling Doc.to_bytes on each individual Doc object. You can also control what data gets saved (see `attrs=["LEMMA", "ENT_IOB", "ENT_TYPE"]`), and you can merge pallets together for easy map/reduce-style processing.

```
    import spacy
    from spacy.tokens import DocBin
    
    doc_bin = DocBin(attrs=["LEMMA", "ENT_IOB", "ENT_TYPE"], store_user_data=True) 
    texts = ["Some text", "Lots of texts...", "..."]
    nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
    for doc in nlp.pipe(texts):
        doc_bin.add(doc)
    bytes_data = doc_bin.to_bytes()

    # Deserialize later, e.g. in a new process
    nlp = spacy.blank("en")
    doc_bin = DocBin().from_bytes(bytes_data)
    docs = list(doc_bin.get_docs(nlp.vocab))
```

[source](https://spacy.io/usage/saving-loading#docs)

Comment: getting this error ERROR:Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked

I.e. convert the python object to str and put it in the json payload.
Later reconstruct the python object back from str

```
import pickle
import codecs
# encode returns bytes so it needs to be decoded to string
pickled = pickle.loads(codecs.decode(pickled.encode(), 'base64')).decode()

type(pickled)  # <class 'str'>

unpickled = pickle.loads(codecs.decode(pickled.encode(), 'base64'))
```